Trying to calculate my macros as a trans man?
I'm a trans man, 20, who is currently transitioning. I am looking to calculate my macros, drop some weight, and tone myself up some, but I am unsure of which options to choose on the calculators.
At the moment, I am three-four months into my transition. My last lab test shows I am measuring in at 262 for T, which is about halfway to the normal range of a cis man at my age. Should I take an average between the macro guidelines, use the male ones, or use the female ones?

300 ng/dL is the bottom end of the “normal” range for a healthy, adult male, so you’re almost already there, according to the one test you did. That said, your dosing schedule significantly affects the result of a t-test. If you’re injecting 75 mg per week, and take a t-test a few hours later, you’ll get a much higher blood result than taking the t-test six days after your last dose. In contrast, injecting 25 mg three times a week would lend itself to less daily variability on blood levels.

You shouldn't use any type of macro guideline or calculator, because due to inter-individual differences in metabolic rates, none of them are accurate enough to be even remotely useful. A calculator that gives you macros that will supposedly be appropriate for weight loss might actually end up causing you to gain weight, or they might end up causing you to starve.
The only sensible way to determine an appropriate caloric intake or macro composition is to measure what you're currently eating, and then adjust that on the basis of your goals. (E.g. if you determined that you are currently eating, on average, 3000 kcal/day, and your weight is stable, then you might start by trying to aim for macros that add up to 2500 kcal/day instead, if your goal is to lose weight.)
